# PersistenceSpecification test and Cascade All

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using a lot *PersistenceSpecification* with fluent nhibernate to test my mappings, but there is a thing that intrigue me.

If I don't put Cascade All in references when performing test "second level distance tables" are not created.

And that seems to be a normal behaviour as it says in fluent wiki:
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing

> Note that, in order for CheckReferences to work, you either need to
>   pass an already persistence entity, or have cascading on the entities
>   you're testing. Otherwise, the test will fail complaining "object
>   references an unsaved transient instance".

**Is that behavior intended?**

To me seems that letting *PersistenceSpecification* recreate the full schema will give it a lot more power.